# Read file content from MongoDB using NoRM driver

Tags: c#, mongodb, norm, gridfs

I'm trying to read the image file stored in a MongoDB, to do that I have following code in my ASP.net MVC 3 projects

```
public FileContentResult ProfileImage(ObjectId id)
{

    using (var db = new MongoSession<User>())
    {
        var user = db.Queryable.Where(p => p.Id == id).FirstOrDefault();
        if (user != null && user.ProfilePicture != null)
        {   
            return File(user.ProfilePicture.Content.ToArray(), user.ProfilePicture.ContentType);
        }

        return null;
    }
}
```

When queried the database I can see the content exist for the `ProfilePicture` file, but when here in the C# project the content length is `0`. Is there anything wrong in the code?

Comment: What type of field is ProfilePicture in Mongo?

Comment: Is user.ProfilePicture.Content.ToArray() an empty array?

Comment: @Aaronontheweb it is `GridFile`. @Judah yes it is empty

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks as if you were embedding `GridFile` in `User`, something like

```
class User 
{ 
    public GridFile ProfilePicture {get; set;}
}
```

That won't work; at least, not through default behavior. `GridFile`s must be treated as first-class citizens, and they must be stored and retrieved using a `GridFileCollection` object:

```
var gridFS = conn.Database.Files();
var file = new GridFile();
// initialize file
gridFS.Save(file);
// query
var file2 = gridFS.FindOne(new { _id = file.Id });
// now, you can iterate file2.Content
```

You can find more working sample code in [NoRM's unit tests](https://github.com/atheken/NoRM/blob/master/NoRM.Tests/GridFS/GridFileCollectionTests.cs).

The reason is that, while `GridFile` is basically a class like any other, the storage scheme for grid files is *very* different. While 'normal' objects are serialized in-place, and one document always corresponds to one object, this is not true for `GridFile`.

Because files can be much larger than the maximum document size in MongoDB, they'll be split up into `chunks`. Thus, when you store a `GridFile`, the driver will have to store the grid file *and* a number of chunks. By default, chunks are 256kB in size, so the number of chunks will depend on the data size. The default collection names are `fs.files` and `fs.chunks`.

All this logic resides in the `GridFileCollection` class, so it won't be executed if you're simply storing an embedded `GridFile` object instead of calling the `Files()` extension explicitly to retrieve the `GridFileCollection`.